# Distict Values Count From Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Example Array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [campain] => exaple1
            [subject] => subject1
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [campain] => exaple2
            [subject] => subject2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [campain] => exaple3
            [subject] => subject3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [campain] => exaple1
            [subject] => subject1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [campain] => exaple2
            [subject] => subject2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [campain] => exaple1
            [subject] => subject1
        )
)
```

Expected Result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [campain] => exaple1
            [subject] => subject1
            [count] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [campain] => exaple2
            [subject] => subject2
            [count] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [campain] => exaple3
            [subject] => subject3
            [count] => 1
        )
)
```

Need Distinct campain,subject & campain count. Subject value can be neglected(i mean no need to take distict subject values as its value will not change for a campain).

Comment: Does `example1` always have `subject1` ?

Comment: dont want o write a full program for you, what's your shot

Comment: Yes @AhmadMobaraki

Comment: @MiteshPant need a short form code to do that. am taking three to four loopings to do that work...So posted for better solution

Comment: Can you post your solution

Comment: Need Function that takes the array and returns the expected result.